# API not exposing items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

**Reworded Question**

Are `items:autodesk.bim360:*` objects available through BIM 360 Team hubs, or only through BIM 360 Docs hubs?

**Original Description**

I am trying to work through the tutorial on https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/ and ran into an issue in Step 4. I initiated collaboration from inside Revit, but when I filter the contents to extension `items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel`, there are no results returned. All the `.rvt` files have extension type `items:autodesk.core:File`.

Here is an abbreviated example:

```
{
  "type": "items",
  "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:RYWSlvzKSVC_5npo6r4IpQ",
  "attributes": {
    "displayName": "C4RForgeAPITestProject.rvt",
    "extension": {
      "type": "items:autodesk.core:File",
      "version": "1.0",
    }
  },
}
```

After going back and trying step 3 again, I noticed that my results from https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/$hubid/projects/$projectId/topFolders had extension type `folders:autodesk.core:Folder` whereas the tutorial showed `folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder`

Potentially a separate issue: I was using BIM 360 Team, but then looked at the fact that all the documents say BIM 360 Docs, and figured I might only be able to get to the C4R models through BIM 360 Docs, so I signed up for a trial there, created a brand new project, went to follow the instructions on http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-AD16C560-F033-448F-8E9E-93939E40F246 to upload a model, but My collaborate dialog only has two options: `Collaborate within your network` and `Collaborate using the cloud`. When I select the latter, I can only see my BIM 360 Team Projects, not my BIM 360 Docs projects.

It feels like I am missing some large piece here. Can anyone help me figure out what that missing piece is?

Comment: Maybe a version of Revit.  2018.3 or 2019 supports Docs.

Comment: Okay, using 2019 I was able to begin collaborating inside of BIM 360 Docs, and can see the file there, but the API is still only returning my BIM 360 Team hub. Will answer this question and ask a different one about why I can't see my BIM 360 Docs hub.

Comment: Docs requires an additional step to activate API. Here is instruction:  
 https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/bim-360-activating-api-access-to-docs/    
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/18/no-custom-integrations-tab/

I know it's confusing.  If you want to have a big picture overview, I collect some info here.  
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/forge/

Comment: I did find that eventually, thanks!

Comment: Okay.  Good luck!